# Fedora 34 - Unable to resolve any name inside docker containers

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, fedora

im on Fedora 34 (= host system) and i have a problem within my docker containers not resolving any domain.
On the host resolution works without problems.

Here's what i tried:

- restart & reinstall docker
- disable firewall
- restart machine
- restart dns
- different docker images
- explicitly setting dns in docker (see below)
- using network mode in docker (see below)
- disabling ipv6

However, i cannot get a name resolved in any container:

```
~ docker run busybox nslookup google.com 
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.36.174

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

As described, it works on the host:

```
~ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.36.206
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4016:809::200e
```

What's also weird, even running with the hosts network or explicitly setting the dns doesn't help:

Tried setting with hosts dns (here it even says timed out...)

```
~ docker run --dns 127.0.0.53 busybox nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Tried with google dns:

```
~ docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.36.238

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

Tried with host network:

```
 ~ docker run --network="host" busybox nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.36.238

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

***Im running out of ideas..anyone has a hint, what's going on here?***

Additional information: It used to work, i didn't change anything on my system as far as i remember that could have an impact on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running the nslookup command with a DNS server specified?
As in: `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`, or in your case: `docker run busybox nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`.
This will help us to eliminate possible network issues in the Docker bridge.

Comment: Here's the output: `~ docker run busybox nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 142.251.36.238

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
`

Comment: Additional Info: I hooked up another system with a brand new fedora 34, same behaviour. Also tried different networks (home / work)

Comment: Okay, since this is still giving you an error, that means there is something really f***ed. I'm thinking about system time, is that correct?

Comment: Actually, I've found a similar issue. Could you try running `docker run busybox nslookup -type=a google.com`?

Other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663711/how-should-i-interpret-a-cant-find-from-nslookup-inside-a-docker-busybox-c

Comment: Yes, that worked immediatly! `~ docker run busybox nslookup -type=a google.com
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 142.251.36.238
`

Comment: Okay so it's just a bug in the latest busybox version on Docker. I would like to refer you to the issue I posted 1 comment ago. I think this is solved then?

Comment: Yes, this helped, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

But you are getting an answer, the 2 lines after `Non-authoritative answer:` are the result (142.251.36.238 is a valid IP address for Google).

What you are not getting is an IPv6 answer by the look of things.

You can just run:

```
docker run busybox nslookup -type=A google.com
```

And it should just return the IP address with out the error.

I suspect that the default behaviour of nslookup in busybox might have changed to return both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses which is why this looks to have changed.

Comment: Yep, this is also a right answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue on Alpine Linux, it is indeed a known bug of busybox >1.28 with IPv6 records. A workaround is installing `bind-tools` to get another `nslookup` binary :

```
apk update && apk add bind-tools
```